# Why is angular calling the server out of order?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller method that I call service methods in. Angular is calling the Server out of order:

controller:

```
$scope.add = function () {
        var waiver = new MyObject();
        service.add(waiver);
        service.getLast().then(function (result) {
            $scope.model.myObjects.push(result.data);
        });
    }
```

Service:

```
this.add = function (waiver) {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/theServer/Add/",
            data: waiver
        });
    };



    this.getLast = function() {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/TheServer/GetLast"
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert("EPIC FAIL");
        })
        ;
    };
```

If I use Chromes debugging tools, angular calls the SERVICE methods in the right order; however, when the actual Server is called GetLast is called before Add. I need these to be called in order on the server.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: `$http` is asynchronous, but you aren't waiting for the first call to resolve before calling the second method, so there is no guaranteed order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling these asyncronously so there is no guarantee of ordering. If you need to guarantee that one call happens before the other, then you need to chain the calls:

```
service.add(waiver)
   .then(function(){
       return service.getLast();
    })
   .then(function (result) {
       $scope.model.myObjects.push(result.data);
   });
```

Comment: Can I call then on a method that doesn't return anything? (add)

Comment: Nope, you need to make it return a promise.

Comment: Also, you can use `.bind` to remove one callback: `service.add(waiver).then(service.getLast.bind(service)).then(function (result) { /* do stuff */});`

Comment: @KevinB I cannot return stuff from the server I get this error whenever I try and return something from any post to web api: "The specified policy origin 'myLocalHost' is invalid. It must not contain a path, query, or fragment."

Comment: @robert sorry... I missed that you weren't returning the promise, but that is a simple change.

Comment: @Robert not from the server, just return from the service.add function.